# Create a grade sheet where it will flag number grades in a certain range by turning that row another color

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a grade sheet where it will flag number grades in a certain range by turning that row another color.

The problem I'm having has to do with grades of Zero.  I have this formula for the other grades, with 90% being the passing mark, so anything above that isn't marked

```
=and($E:$E<90%, $E:$E>0%)
```

The problem is that apparently the value of an empty cell is considered to be 0 by the spreadsheet.  If I did a conditional format with the following:

```
=$E:$E=0
```

the spreadsheet lights up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isblank()` to format blank cells the way you want to. For example

```
=or(and($E:$E<90%, $E:$E>0%), isblank($E:$E))
```

or

```
=or(and($E:$E<90%, $E:$E>0%), not(isblank($E:$E)))
```

By the way, you can simply enter `$E1` here instead of `$E:$E` - the conditional formatting formula can be written as it applies to the upper left corner of the range.

Comment: Here's a link to what the table will look like: [Example Table](http://s27.postimg.org/itizjoctv/Example_Table.png) - as you can see, one of the problems is that the Grades column will contain four different classes of values.  There will be some blank cells, some that contain o% that I want to highlight that row in red, from 1%-89% that will be highlighted yellow, and then 90% and above that won't have highlighting.

Comment: The root cause here is poor data organization. The comments should have been placed in one cell (line breaks can be created with Ctrl-Enter) instead of spanning across several rows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it to work. Here's the formula I used:

```
=and($E:$E=0%;not(isBlank($E:$E)))
```

The organization of the cells is because there is another layer to the data that I forgot to include in the example.  Each grade is composed of different sections that are graded separately.  For example

English-90%
Creative Writing - Pass
Grammar - Fail